# How do I create a non-bare bundled repository in Git

Tags: git, dropbox, tortoisegit

This is to be able to use Tortoise Git on existing files on Dropbox.
(So Tortoise Git should be able to recognize the repository)

(The repository has to be one file - therefore bundled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think you can: as far as I’m aware, Git is not capable of treating a bundle file as a repository in its own right.

Comment: OK - it is often mentioned in connection with Dropbox - I guess it doesn't help the way I thought it would matter.